# Trouble with .NET 6 Login on Razor Pages

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, authentication, razor

I scaffolded a login page and am trying to log in with user name and password (somehow they set it default to email and password, but I changed it). Here's my code for the login model:

```cs
// Licensed to the .NET Foundation under one or more agreements.
// The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license.
#nullable disable

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using datacuss.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace datacuss.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<DatacussUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

        public LoginModel(SignInManager<DatacussUser> signInManager, ILogger<LoginModel> logger)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [TempData]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public class InputModel
        {
            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [Required]
            [DataType (DataType.Text)]
            [Display(Name = "User Name")]
            public string UserName { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
            public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
            }

            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.UserName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

And the code for the actual login page:

```cs
@page
@model LoginModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Log in";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <section>
            <form id="account" method="post">
                <h2>Use a local account to log in.</h2>
                <hr />
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input asp-for="Input.UserName" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true" />
                    <label asp-for="Input.UserName" class="form-label"></label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" autocomplete="current-password" aria-required="true" />
                    <label asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-label"></label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label asp-for="Input.RememberMe" class="form-label">
                            <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Input.RememberMe" />
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Input.RememberMe)
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button id="login-submit" type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary">Log in</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>
                        <a id="forgot-password" asp-page="./ForgotPassword">Forgot your password?</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a asp-page="./Register" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl">Register as a new user</a>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a id="resend-confirmation" asp-page="./ResendEmailConfirmation">Resend email confirmation</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
        <section>
            <h3>Use another service to log in.</h3>
            <hr />
            @{
                if ((Model.ExternalLogins?.Count ?? 0) == 0)
                {
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            There are no external authentication services configured. See this <a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715">article
                            about setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services</a>.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <form id="external-account" asp-page="./ExternalLogin" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                @foreach (var provider in Model.ExternalLogins!)
                                {
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="provider" value="@provider.Name" title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">@provider.DisplayName</button>
                                }
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                }
            }
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

I'm getting the `Invalid Login Attempt` error. I'm using the standard .NET user schema on a SQL Server Database (got connection working though). What's going on here?

Well, switching Email to UserName for one. That doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use scaffolded to generate code about Asp.Net Core identity, When you register user, It will generate `Email` and `Password` field for user to input. Framework will set Username property equal to Email property automatically. When value of Username does not equal to Email and you use Username to log in, It will show `Invalid Login Attempt`.

If you don't wanna this. You can follow these steps:

In `Register.cshtml.cs`, Add `UserName` property in `InputModel`, Write code for user to input `UserName` in frontend.

In `OnPostAsync` action, Change

```
await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
```

to

```
await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.UserName, CancellationToken.None);
```

In this case user can input his own username when register account.

[image]

Now user can use their username to log in successfully.

[image]

Comment: Well, we're not going to use the register in the main sense of things. Users can't register themselves onto the system. Someone else has to do it, which is the way it's going to be. I set the two initial users directly on the database and hashed the passwords directly on a web app to use.

Comment: In default case, Username must equals to Email in database so that user can login, But in my answer, User can login with it's Username, If you don't wanna user to register, You can just hidden the register endpoint, I think it is the solution about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I wish my given solution will work

- Verify user credentials match database

In the OnPostAsync method, add a check before sign-in to verify user exists:

```
    // Query to validate username/password
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.UserName);

if (user != null) {
  // User exists, verify password below
}
else {
  ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username");
  return Page();
}
```

- Check user account status

After checking user exists, also verify status:

```
if (user.LockoutEnabled && user.LockoutEnd > DateTime.Now) {
  ModelState.AddModelError("", "User account locked out");
  return Page();
}

if (!user.EmailConfirmed) {
  ModelState.AddModelError("", "Email not confirmed");
  return Page(); 
}
```

- Log detailed identity errors

In OnPostAsync method:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.UserName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

if (!result.Succeeded) {
  var errorDesc = string.Join(", ", result.Errors);
  _logger.LogWarning($"Invalid login attempt: {errorDesc}");
  
  // Return error
}
```

- Test with hardcoded valid credentials

Comment out model binding and try known good values:

```
//var userName = Input.UserName; 
//var password = Input.Password;

var userName = "TestUser";
var password = "StrongPassword123"; 

var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, false);
```

It would validate where the issue is occurring and add proper logging and error handling.

Comment: How do I define the _userManager here? In the LoginModel constructor?